# Why is Kotlin String.split with a regex string not the same as Java?

Tags: java, regex, split, kotlin

I have the following Java code:

```
String str = "12+20*/2-4";
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

arr = str.split("\\p{Punct}");

//expected: arr = {12,20,2,4}
```

I want the equivalent Kotlin code, but `.split("\\p{Punct}")` doesn't work. I don't understand the documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you should using `String#split(Regex)` instead, for example:

```
val str = "12+20*/2-4";
val arr = str.split("\\p{Punct}".toRegex());
//  ^--- but the result is ["12","20","","2","4"]

val arr2 = arr.filter{ !it.isBlank() };
//  ^--- you can filter it as further, and result is: ["12","20","2","4"]
```

**OR** you can split more *Punctuation*s by using `\\p{Punct}+` , for example:

```
val arr = str.split("\\p{Punct}+".toRegex())
//  ^--- result is: ["12","20","2","4"]
```

**OR** *invert* the regex and using `Regex#findAll` instead, and you can find out the negative numbers in this way. for example:

```
val str ="12+20*/2+(-4)";

val arr ="(?<!\\d)-?[^\\p{Punct}]+".toRegex().findAll(str).map{ it.value }.toList()
//  ^--- result is ["12","20","2","-4"]
//   negative number is found   ---^
```

Answer (score 7):

For regex behavior, your argument **must** be of type `Regex`, not merely a `String` containing special regex characters.

Most string manipulation methods in Kotlin ([`replace`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html), [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html), etc.) can take both `String` and `Regex` arguments, but you must convert your `String` to `Regex` if you want regex-specific matching.

This conversion can be done using `String.toRegex()` or `Regex(String)`:

```
val str = "12+20*/2-4";
str.split("\\p{Punct}".toRegex()) //this
str.split(Regex("\\p{Punct}")) //or this
```

Currently [`split`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/split.html) is treating that first backslash as an escape character instead of recognizing it as a special regex sequence.

---

as mentioned by @holi-java in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064905/3745896) this will match an empty string between `*` and `/` giving `["12","20","","2","4"]`. You can use `"\\p{Punct}+"` as your regex to avoid this. (Though note that Java gives the output *with* this empty string unless a `+` is included there as well.)

Answer (score 3):

You can call

```
str.split(Regex("{\\p{Punct}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

From Kotlin 1.6 there is a better and easier way of doing this.

```
fun main() {
    val str = "12+20*/2-4"
    val regex = "\\p{Punct}".toRegex()
    var arr = str.splitToSequence(regex);
    arr.forEach(){
            println(it.toString())
    }
}
```

**Reference:** https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew16.html#splitting-regex-into-a-sequence